# Ajax POST body is blank when hitting API method

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm loosely following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-crud-with-reactjs-and-entity-framework) to create a basic app which posts form data to a local API, and then adds the data to a local database.

The author of the tutorial POSTs a variable of `FormData(event.target)` which comes up as a blank object for me (no idea why, I used the exact code to test this) - regardless, I'd prefer to use the values in `this.state` anyway.

The `state` values are populated as expected, but the data isn't transmitted to the API method, all the values are null ([screenshot of Visual Studio debug view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ShXy.jpg))

I've tried playing around with the `Content-Type` (application/json, multipart/form-data, application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and I've tried sending a JSON string (`JSON.stringify(post)`) instead of a state object, but none of these has worked.

The outputs were:

#### Object

> {id: 1, date: Sat Apr 27 2019 10:46:49 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time), name: "Tom", company: "Acme Inc", message: "Test message"}

#### String

> {"id":1,"date":"2019-04-27T09:46:49.361Z","name":"Tom","company":"Acme Inc","message":"Test message"}

### The component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class AddPost extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            date: new Date(),
            name: "",
            company: "",
            message: ""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePost = this.handlePost.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handlePost(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const post = this.state;
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', 'api/Posts/Create');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send(post);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handlePost}>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <button className="btn btn-primary"> Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

### The API class/methods

```
// Posts.cs
public partial class Posts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

```
// PostsController.cs
PostsDataAccessLayer dal = new PostsDataAccessLayer();

[HttpPost("[action]")]
[Route("api/Posts/Create")]
public int Create(Posts posts)
{
    return dal.AddPost(posts);
}
```

```
// PostsDataAccessLayer.cs
DotNetCoreAndReactContext db = new DotNetCoreAndReactContext();

public int AddPost(Posts posts)
{
    try
    {
        db.Posts.Add(posts);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return 1;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

### The table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Posts] (
    [Id]      INT           NOT NULL,
    [Date]    DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    [Name]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Company] VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Message] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use this maybe it work ` Create([Frombody]Posts posts)`

Comment: @hassan.ef - you are my hero! You would not believe how long I've spent trying to troubleshoot this and all it required was `[FromBody]` :/

Comment: @ Tom, your welcome, I put it in answer and you accept that, I hope helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put [FromBody] in action signature like this:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[Route("api/Posts/Create")]
public int Create([FromBody]Posts posts)
{
    return dal.AddPost(posts);
}
```